# Word order in question with very long subject

Tags: word-order, questions, subject-verb-inversion

The normal word order for a wh- question in English is: wh- + auxiliary + subject + verb.

Hence the sentence below should be correct:

> *What might the consequences of the loss of diversity of plant genetic resources be?*

However, it sounds a bit strange to me (I am not an English native speaker).

The following sentence sounds better, although according to the rule above it is incorrect:

> *What might be the consequences of the loss of diversity of plant genetic resources?*

Which sentence is the correct one?

Comment: They're both correct, the difference being that, in the former, *the consequences* is the subject and, in the latter, *what* is the subject.

Comment: "The rule above" describes one basic structure. It does not describe every possible variation. Syntax is not a matter of word following word; it's a matter of constituents and variations. In this case the constituent is the [Verb Phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) _might be `NP`_, which can appear as well. The rule you quoted is deficient, in that it doesn't allow _might be_ to count as "auxiliary". Whoever writes these rules has no idea what they're doing.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Thanks for your answer. This rule is taught to non-English speakers to help them learn to ask questions in English. I think it does a good job for many questions (Where do I go? What can you do? When will she arrive? etc.) but it may be too simplistic for more complex grammatical structures. So if I understand correctly in the second sentence the structure is: Subject (What) + Verb phrase (might be) + Noun phrase (the consequences...), i.e. a structure without the "traditional" subject-auxiliary inversion. Is that acceptable only in spoken English or in written English too? Thanks

Comment: No, the prepositional phrase is part of the verb phrase -- it's the predicate -- and the noun phrase is part of the prepositional phrase. The phrase train _might be_ works best as a single auxiliary (afterall, its present tense version _may be_ is already a single word in many constructions). The actual rule (explained in [the link(http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf)) is that **the first auxiliary verb** inverts with the subject NP in actual (but not embedded) questions. The issue is whether _might be_ can be considered a single (therefore first) auxiliary verb. Apparently it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What might the consequences of the loss of diversity of plant
>      genetic resources be?
> 2. What might be the consequences of the loss of diversity of plant genetic resources?

In the first question, the subject is *the consequences of the loss of diversity of plant genetic resources*. The interrogative word *what* is the complement of the verb *BE*. Because it has moved to the front of the sentence it has triggered subject auxiliary inversion, and we see *might* change places with the subject.

In the second sentence, *what* is the subject of the sentence. The noun phrase *the consequences of the loss of diversity of plant genetic resources* is the complement of the verb *BE*. Because *what* is already at the front of the sentence, it doesn't cause any inversion.

In short both sentences are perfectly grammatical.

We can make the difference clear by showing the following in situ versions of questions 1 and 2:

1'. The consequences of the loss of diversity of plant genetic resources might be *what*?

2'. *What* might be the consequences of the loss of diversity of plant genetic resources?

Sentence 2' has the same word order as sentence 2, because *what* is already in the subject position. In sentence 1', however, we see *what* in a position that would have been filled by a specific value or word in the corresponding declarative sentence. It therefore looks quite different from 1.

Answer (score 0):

> What might the consequences of the loss of diversity of plant genetic
>   resources be?
>
> What might be the consequences of the loss of diversity of plant
>   genetic resources?

I like #2 better. But it can be shortened.  What are "genetic *resources*"?

**What might result from the loss of plant genetic diversity?**