# "What would have been your chances?" vs "What would your chances have been?"

Tags: grammar, questions

"What would have been your chances?" vs "What would your chances have been?"

Which one is grammatically correct and why?

Comment: Chances are that you should be asking questions like this on English Language Learners, after providing a complete example of the sentence in which you wish to use one of these constructions.

Comment: They are both complete sentences, aren't they?

Comment: Ok, but they need a sentence with the context so one can assess whether the tense is correct. Is it “if you had bet on…”? But, in any case, there is no *grammatical* difference between the two options, they just differ in word order in a way any native speaker would realize is a matter of stylistic taste. I repeat, ELL is the place for this sort of thing, and there is no shame in that.

Comment: @David It's not that obvious an analysis here. Note that 'Where would the bathroom have been?' is mandatory, ?/*'Where would have been the bathroom?' being unacceptable. And *'Where would have been you?' is outlandish. As is *'What would have been John if he hadn't gone into teaching?' // 'What would have been your chances ...' is in a rather literary style, and idiomatic although not all such structures are.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — I agree there are exceptions. There are always exceptions in English, as you well know. And the same question asked by a child and a university professor might require two very different answers, unless the context provided showed that the child was precocious or the professor senile. If the poster had provided context we could have judged the level at which a response was appropriate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word order in: What would be the further steps?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233274/word-order-in-what-would-be-the-further-steps) Also [Word order in question with very long subject](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208423/word-order-in-question-with-very-long-subject/208452#208452)

Comment: @David If you examine the mission statement of ELU, you will see that it's _not_ intended _primarily_ as a Q and A service, but rather uses questions as a platform to explore correct usage. Even if a question has been generated by a spam generator, it can be fair game. Non-ELU-standard answers should never be given, but equally some questions can be answered in ways helpful to linguists if less so to the questioner. And as Greg Lee points out in an earlier and excellent answer, ...

Comment: [thanks to FF] 'Having a complicated phrase embedded within parts of a higher level phrase causes some difficulty in comprehension. Such constraints were first explored by Susumu Kuno, and they are discussed in several places in McCawley's The Syntactic Phenomena of English, which also gives references to Kuno's earlier work.'

Answer (score 0):

Some general recommendations in English prose syntax are to avoid separating a subject from its predicate, and to avoid interposing adverbs, objects, or other words into a predicate with multiple parts. Your predicate is "would have been", which we'd want to keep together whenever possible. Of course, as with all such "rules", writers can choose to except them with cause. As far as meaning, I don't see much difference.

Comment: So what about "Where have you been?" ? Are you saying we should say instead "Where have been you?" ?

Comment: As I said, it's a general syntactical guideline ("general recommendations"), to discourage students writing sentences where the predicate, as in this interjection right now right here, is separated from it's predicate ("predicate"#1=subject, "is separated"=predicate) by too much interrupting information. There are exceptions (and, as far as grammatical rules go, English has more exceptions than any other language that I'm familiar with).

Comment: The example sentence is a question. It's normal in English, usually mandatory, to use subject auxiliary inversion. In other words it's normal for the first verb in the predicate to appear before the subject.  The first verb is therefore usually separated from the rest of the predicate by said subject: "What **did** she **say**?". Nobody recommends keeping the auxiliary together with the rest of the predicate in questions (apart from subject questions).